# Blazor/API Routing Issue - Getting Started

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

My API keeps blowing up on this section:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
}
```

I think it's to do with adding a variable (id)

```
 [Route("[api/controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class NotificationController : Controller
        {
            private  readonly INotificationService _notificationService;
    
            public NotificationController()
            {
                _notificationService = Services.NotificationService();
            }
    
            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public IActionResult GetNotificationsByAccountId(string id)
            {
                var notis = _notificationService.FindAllActiveByAccountId(id);
    
    
                return Ok();
            }

}
```

Error 1:
For action: 'Solution.Api.Controllers.NotificationController.GetNotificationsByAccountId (Solution.Api)'
Error: While processing template '[api/controller]/{id}', a replacement value for the token 'api/controller' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.

Ideas?

Comment: Hi @D-W, if my reply is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer, thanks:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the Route attribute like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

[controller] in the route template is a token which ASP.NET Core will automatically replace when adding the route to the route table